# Setting static port number on Visual Studio Dev Server with a WebSite project

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, asp.net-development-serv, vs-web-site-project

I have a WebSite project in Visual Studio 2008 (not a Web Application project!)

How do I set the ASP.NET Development startup port to a static port in a WebSite project?

Comment: Can't be done. Perhaps if you tell us why you'd prefer this we can suggest an alternate solution.

Comment: It's a legacy project, and currently converting it into a Web Application is not worth the effort just to get the static port number working.  It is something we will do in the future, just not now...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To specify a port for the ASP.NET Development Server - **WebSite / WebServices projects**

1. In Solution Explorer, click the name of the application.
2. In the Properties pane, click the down-arrow beside **Use
   dynamic ports** and select False from
   the dropdown list. This will enable
   editing of the Port number property.
3. In the Properties pane, click the text box beside Port number and type
   in a port number. Click outside of 
   the Properties pane.This saves the property settings.
4. Each time you run a file-system
   Web site within Visual Web Developer, the ASP.NET
   Development Server will listen on the specified port.

Comment: +1 superb, been bugging me for months this. I would recommend hitting F4 to get to the properties!

Answer (score 4):

Press F4 to get the Properties Pane. And then one can get the [option mentioned by Backslash17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126491/setting-static-port-number-on-visual-studio-dev-server-with-a-website-project/1126560#1126560)

Answer (score 1):

For web site assigning port is not possible form VS Properties Page interface but if you start your web site **from command line** then you can assign the port (If you want to debug the site you can attach after starting the web site)

WebDev.WebServer40.exe

path is

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\"
or
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\"

ASP.NET Development Server Usage:
WebDev.WebServer40 /port: /path: [/vpath:]

Example:

**WebDev.WebServer40 /port:8080 /path:"c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp" /vpath:"/MyApp"**

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done with a Website project, the port number is randomly assigned.

It's only possible with a Web App Project