# How to use WebClient.DownloadData(to a local DummyPage.aspx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, path, localhost

I'm following a tutorial on this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx

Now I'm stuck at these codes

```
private const string DummyPageUrl = 
    "http://localhost/TestCacheTimeout/WebForm1.aspx";

private void HitPage()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadData(DummyPageUrl);
}
```

My local application address has a port number after "localhost", so how can I get the full path (can it be done in Application_Start method)? I want it to be very generic so that it can work in any cases.

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE

I tried this in the Application_Start and it runs fine, but return error right away when published to IIS7

```
String path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is calling back to the same server, perhaps use the `Request` object:

```
var url = new Uri(Request.Url, "/TestCacheTimeout/WebForm1.aspx").AbsoluteUri;
```

Otherwise, store the *other* server's details in a config file or the database, and just give it the right value.

But a better question would be: why would you talk via http *to yourself*? Why not just call a class method? Personally I'd be using an *external* scheduled job to do this.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is following the instructions from that site to simulate a service that can keep running and doing some stuffs for me over time.

Comment: if you have the webapp running in a virtual dir, you could/should use `var url = Request.Url.ToString().Substring(0, Request.Url.ToString().LastIndexOf('/')) + "/WebForm1.aspx";`

Comment: There's a problem with this if you deploying to a environment where your using a application folder....

Answer (score 1):

You need an answer that works when you roll out to a different environment that maybe has a virtual application folder.

```
// r is Request.Url
var url = new Uri(r, System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Folder/folder/page.aspx")).AbsoluteUri;
```

This will work in all cases and no nasty surprises when you deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're using the ASP.NET development server that's built-in to Visual Studio, which has a tendency to change port numbers by default. If that's the case, then you might try simply configuring the development server to always use the same port, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126491/setting-static-pport-number-on-visual-studio-dev-server-with-a-website-project). Then just add the port number to your URL, like so:

```
private const string DummyPageUrl = 
"http://localhost:42001/TestCacheTimeout/WebForm1.aspx";
```