# Running Webdriver against Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I am currently using webdriver to run tests on my website. The website is currently being run using IIS manager, so my tests run against the path: localhost/path/to/my/website.

The issue with this is if I want to have my tests run against the latest version of my website, I need to do a full build and redeploy of the site, which can take a long time. I was wondering if there was a way I could run webdriver against visual studio's emulator instead. The path to that usually ends up being localhost:(some port number)/(some URL), but I still need a way to start the emulator and run against the right port number.

To clarify, I'm running the tests from VS just fine. What I want to do is run the tests against VS's emulator. So I need a way to start the emulator before running the tests.

I was also able to find out that the website always runs with the host/port: http://localhost:62880/ So how all I need to know is how to start the emulator from WebDriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find [this solution](http://www.michael-whelan.net/testing-mvc-application-with-iis-express-webdriver/).

The basic idea is to publish your website locally to a non-source controlled folder (this is done by modifying the project), then use IIS Express to run the website on a given port.

Comment: Wow! that's interesting

Comment: Would you expand on the link for the benefit of readers? We tend to discourage link-only answers here.

Comment: @halfer Sure, but I will keep the link since it will explain the process way better than I ever could

Answer (score 0):

I believe once you have the test assembly build you can run them on **NUnit Console**. I usually copy the bin directory and drag and drop the `dll` on [NUnit Console](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download).

[image]

Having said that I am not entirely sure how to run vs emulator on a static port all the time. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126491/setting-static-port-number-on-visual-studio-dev-server-with-a-website-project) may help.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Running the tests isnt really an issue, I'm running the tests from VS just fine. What i want to do is run the tests against VS's emulator. So I need a way to start the emulator before running the tests. The static port answer does help though.