# How to solve redirect_uri_mismatch i ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have created ASP.NET MVC web application to integrate with google calendar API.

I have followed the  documentation in Google sites. I have set up the project in Google Developer console as follows:

[image]

I have also downloaded the credentials files after creating the project but while using it i am getting `uri_mismatch` error every time.

[image]

How can this be solved?

My code for authorization is :

```
string jsonFile = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/credentials.json");

            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream(jsonFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                //string credPath = "token.json";
                string credPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/token");
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
```

Comment: Isn't the mismatch obvious? `127.0.0.1` isn't `localhost`. And the ports are also different. Presumably you've misconfigured this somehow so it uses localhost in one place and 127.x in the other place. Of course we can't tell you specifically what's wrong without seeing more detail.

Comment: @ADyson From where I can cahange thar from?

Comment: It may just be your startup settings in Visual Studio meaning that the application is running in a different setup

Comment: @ADyson the author of this question is not configuring it its done automatically by the google .net client library.

Comment: @BirazDahal it would be a good idea to post the code you are using to authorize your application I may understand what you are doing but it would be better if others could see it as well.  I assume you are following  [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc)

Comment: @DaImTo Not exactly that one but similar. I have posted my code for authorization above

Comment: @BirazDahal unless this is an installed application that code isnt going to work hosted on a web server, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect uri you set in Google Developer console must exactly match where you are sending from and expecting the response to be returned to.

I am going to assume that you are using the Google .net client library because your response says /authorize which is configured with in the library

## Solution for uri_mismatch

in Google developer console add

```
http://localhost:63972/authorize
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:63972/authorize
```

but make sure that you have a static port set up in your IDE ([visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1126560/1841839)) or you are going to have the same issue again.

## Tip web application vs installed application

The code you have posted uses `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` which is designed for use with installed applications.   When the authorization window opens it will open on the machine the code is running on.  While you are in development this will work as its going to open on your dev machine but when you try to release this to the server its not going to work.

You should be using `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` for following this example [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc)

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4
{
    public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
    {
        private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                        ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });

        public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
        {
            // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
            // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
            // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
            // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
            // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
            var user = controller.Session["user"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = Guid.NewGuid();
                controller.Session["user"] = user;
            }
            return user.ToString();

        }

        public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
        {
            get { return flow; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DalmTo I tried with this process, ubt I am getting result.credentials as null always. 

var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
               AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);
I triend the above code to get the credentials and always getting null. Is there any thing to do more on Google API Console? I have already added Authorize redirected files and also generated the client ID and client secret Id

Comment: If you are having an issue with the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow i would open a new question with your new code.  As its unrelated to the question you have posted here.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!  It worked Finally in the server also. but there is one problem i am facing  each time I open in the different browser I need to login to gmail account. Is there any way just to log in the account just for once because I need to set the event in my clients google calendar with the email i am logging in.